# Entity Framework optimistic concurrency exceptions occur when multi SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I using Entity Framework 6. After calling `SaveChanges` method twice in my code, after `DeleteObject`, a `ConcurrencyException` occurred:

```
entities.DeleteObject(pu);

// First time           
entities.Context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None);

// everything is ok

// Second Time     
entities.Context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None);

// Concurrency exception
```

But with using `AddObject` this exception did not occur !

Exception message is:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

How I can control multiple `SaveChanges` calls before `AcceptAllChanges` without a concurrency exception?

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling the AcceptAllChanges() method before the second save? My understanding is that if you use SaveOptions.None, the context keeps the changes so they can be resubmitted to the database. If the first SaveChanges() succeeds, than the rowversion is updated in the db, but in the context, everything is kept as it was, so the second time it causes the conflict on the rowversion.

Comment: doesn't exist rowversion or timestamp column in table pu only exist datetime2 , money , int

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction

```js
var yourContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;

try {
    yourContext.Connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope()) {
        
        //you can implement entities.DeleteObject(pu) here

        db.SaveChanges();

        // Do something else

        db.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Complete();
    }
} finally {
    yourContext.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: TransactionScope is for revert , but my question is why every things is OK in first call but i get error for second call and don't have any code  between savechanges